# Java List Group by Model property adding values

Tags: java, sorting, grouping

I have a List of Teams with the following properties:

```
public class Team {
private String name; //get;set
private int score;//get;set
}
```

Is there a way to group the results of the list by Name while adding the scores?
The List can contain multiple of the same team but with different scores:

- TeamA - 3
- TeamB - 3
- TeamA - 3
- TeamC - 0
- TeamB - 1
- TeamD - 1
- TeamE - 1

And the final list that I want to achive is something like this (ordered by score and when draw, alphabetically):

- TeamA - 6
- TeamB - 4
- TeamD - 1
- TeamE - 1
- TeamC - 0

Right now, I got this with the help of frascu's answer:

```
teams.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getName)
            .thenComparing(Team::getScore, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
Map<String, Integer> map = teams.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Team::getName, summingInt(Team::getScore)));
```

But when I print the result from the map I get this:

- TeamA - 6
- TeamB - 4
- TeamC - 0
- TeamD - 1
- TeamE - 1

The score 0 is being ordered as higher than 1

Comment: There are **no** maps or streams in the snippets you've posted. Please, don't get offended but every Question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort, see [*How do I ask a good question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If that everything you've tried, it would be beneficial for you if you try harder (if your goal is to attain new knowledge).

Comment: *"group the results of the list by Name while adding the scores"* - it's even unclear what should be the resulting type. Consider improving the question by introducing a **code-attempt** which clarifies this moment (use *edit* button, or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73902805/edit)).

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko thanks for the clarification, I made the corresponding changes and what I want to achieve, I also added the code of what I have right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **not** necessary to sort the source list unless you don't want it to be sorted as well.

**Note** that by sorting the source list you can **not** ensure that entries of the map would be stored in sorted order because the map is expected to contain the accumulated score (i.e. multiple elements in the list could contribute to a single map entry). Hence, sorting has to be applied right in the stream **after** grouping the data by team-name and generating the total score of each team.

In order to maintain entries in sorted order, you need a `Map` implementation which is capable of maintaining the order. When *mapFactory* is not specified, collector would give you a general purpose implementation (for now it's `HashMap`) which doesn't meet this requirement.

The possible option is to use a `LinkedHashMap`. **Note**: because entries need to be ordered by both *value* and *key*, you can't achieve required ordering with a `TreeMap`, which maintains sorted order based on *keys*.

That how it might be implemented:

```
List<Team> teams = List.of(
    new Team("TeamA", 3),
    new Team("TeamB", 3),
    new Team("TeamA", 3),
    new Team("TeamC", 0),
    new Team("TeamB", 1),
    new Team("TeamD", 1),
    new Team("TeamE", 1)
);
        
Map<String, Integer> scoreByName = teams.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Team::getName,     // keyMapper
        Team::getScore,    // valueMapper
        Integer::sum       // mergeFunction
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError("duplicates are not expected"); }, // because the source of the stream is a Map, and there couldn't be a key that occure more than once
        LinkedHashMap::new // mapFactory
    ));
        
scoreByName.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " -> " + v));
```

*Output:*

```
TeamA -> 6
TeamB -> 4
TeamD -> 1
TeamE -> 1
TeamC -> 0
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/wlE)

Answer (score 0):

Using `thenComparing` you can apply a second sort on the elements that have the same name. In your case, you need to call `reverseOrder` in order to apply descending order to the score.

```java
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Team::getName)
                    .thenComparing(Team::getScore, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot on the progress of this problem, I updated the question since it was lacking information and a new scenario